How do I Access Both Eye Images from LAV Video Decoder for 3D Blu-ray in C#?
I want to decode a 3D Blu-ray and handle the left and right eye images in my C# application. I have constructed a filter using DirectShowLib with a SampleGrabber to display and inspect the raw RGB32 output buffer from the LAV Video Decoder. I'm playing a ripped 3D Blu-ray by opening the correct 00800.mpls playlist file.
The problem is that the RGB32 frame buffer from the LAV Video Decoder contains only one eye image at 1920x1080 and is 8294400 bytes in size, which fits only one eye at 1920x1080 in RGB32 format. The H.264 MVC plugin is enabled in the decoder settings. The eyes are not interleaved, not top-bottom, not left-right, not alternating and not packed; only one eye is in the frame buffer.
However, when I use MadVR as the video renderer and enable 3D playback, it can display both eyes! MadVR is not using a 3D effect to generate the second frame because it only displays the second eye with the 3D Blu-ray, which uses main and differential m2ts files for the left and right eyes.
What I want to know is: where is MadVR getting the other eye from and how can I access this second eye frame buffer in my C# application?
These are the methods that construct the graph:
private void SetupGraph(string videoPath){
    _graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
    _mediaControl = (IMediaControl)_graphBuilder;
    var splitterClsid = new Guid("B98D13E7-55DB-4385-A33D-09FD1BA26338");
    var lavSplitter = CreateFilterByClsid(splitterClsid);
    _graphBuilder.AddFilter(lavSplitter, "LAV Splitter Source");
    var fileSource = (IFileSourceFilter)lavSplitter;
    fileSource.Load(videoPath, null);
    var videoDecoderClsid = new Guid("EE30215D-164F-4A92-A4EB-9D4C13390F9F");
    var lavVideoDecoder = CreateFilterByClsid(videoDecoderClsid);
    _graphBuilder.AddFilter(lavVideoDecoder, "LAV Video Decoder");
    var audioDecoderClsid = new Guid("E8E73B6B-4CB3-44A4-BE99-4F7BCB96E491");
    var lavAudioDecoder = CreateFilterByClsid(audioDecoderClsid);
    _graphBuilder.AddFilter(lavAudioDecoder, "LAV Audio Decoder");
    _sampleGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;
    _sampleGrabber.SetCallback(new SampleGrabberCallback(), 1);
    var mediaType = new AMMediaType{ majorType = MediaType.Video, subType = MediaSubType.RGB32, formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo };
    _sampleGrabber.SetMediaType(mediaType);
    _sampleGrabber.SetBufferSamples(true);
    _sampleGrabberCallback = new SampleGrabberCallback();
    _sampleGrabberCallback.FrameCaptured += (o, args) => Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {DrawFrame(o, args);}));
    _sampleGrabber.SetCallback(_sampleGrabberCallback, 1);
    _graphBuilder.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)_sampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
    ConnectFilters(_graphBuilder, lavSplitter, lavVideoDecoder, "Video");
    ConnectFilters(_graphBuilder, lavSplitter, lavAudioDecoder, "Audio");
    ConnectFilters(_graphBuilder, lavVideoDecoder, (IBaseFilter)_sampleGrabber, "Output");
    var defaultDirectSound = CreateFilterByClsid(new Guid("79376820-07D0-11CF-A24D-0020AFD79767"));
    _graphBuilder.AddFilter(defaultDirectSound, "Default DirectSound Device");
    ConnectFilters(_graphBuilder, lavAudioDecoder, defaultDirectSound, "Output");
    _mediaControl.Run();
}
private IBaseFilter CreateFilterByClsid(Guid clsid){
    var comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid);
    return (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
}
private void ConnectFilters(IGraphBuilder graphBuilder, IBaseFilter sourceFilter, IBaseFilter targetFilter, string pinCategory){
    try{
        Console.WriteLine($"Connecting filters: {sourceFilter} to {targetFilter} with category: {pinCategory}");
        var sourceOutputPin = GetPin(sourceFilter, PinDirection.Output, pinCategory);
        if(sourceOutputPin == null){
            Console.WriteLine("Source output pin is null.");
            return;
        }
        var targetInputPin = GetPin(targetFilter, PinDirection.Input);
        if(targetInputPin == null){
            Console.WriteLine("Target input pin is null.");
            return;
        }
        var hr = graphBuilder.ConnectDirect(sourceOutputPin, targetInputPin, null);
        if(hr != 0) Console.WriteLine($"Failed to connect filters. HR: {hr}");
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine($"ConnectFilters Exception: {ex.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
private IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, PinDirection pinDirection, string category = null){
    var hr = filter.EnumPins(out var pinEnum);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    var pins = new IPin[1];
    while(pinEnum.Next(1, pins, IntPtr.Zero) == 0){
        pins[0].QueryDirection(out var pinDir);
        if(pinDir == pinDirection){
            if(category != null){
                pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out var pinInfo);
                if(pinInfo.name.Contains(category)){
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pinInfo.filter);
                    return pins[0];
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pinInfo.filter);
            } else{ return pins[0]; }
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Pin not found.");
}


The LAV Video Decoder uses the following C++ IMediaSample3D interface in native code to get the stereo frame buffer from the regular IMediaSample but I'm unable to use the interface in my C# code because the IMediaSample3D interface is not registered in the COM registry and I get 0x80004002 which is E_NOINTERFACE.
interface __declspec(uuid("E92D790E-BF54-43C4-B394-8CA0A41BF9EC")) IMediaSample3D : public IMediaSample2
{
  STDMETHOD(Enable3D)() = 0;
  STDMETHOD(GetPointer3D)(BYTE **ppBuffer) = 0;
};


No idea, probably no 3d support in Direct Show. Have you read this thread https://www.reddit.com/r/bigscreen/comments/xhl9yn/any_video_players_that_can_read_3d_blurays_in_3d/ ?

The LAV Video Decoder uses the IMediaSample3D interface with GUID E92D790E-BF54-43C4-B394-8CA0A41BF9EC to get the stereo frame buffer from the regular IMediaSample but I'm unable to use the interface in my C# code for some reason i get 0x80004002 which is E_NOINTERFACE.
